# C - Error: cannot open source file "funcs.h"

Tags: c, header

The header file is in the same folder as the other files, it's #include'ed and all, but some reason the other source files just can't find it. Same with compiler. Help?

Comment: How can we help you with the information you've provided?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Did you tell it to look for include files in that folder? If not, that's your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should try `#include "funcs.h"` instead of `#include <funcs.h>`

Comment: Hey, there actually are people who bother to give proper answers instead of ridiculing someone's ignorance! Who woulda thunk?
*aimed at comments above*